# Adding JDBC to project in Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I haven't been able to figure this error out for a few days my program will compile but has the following error when I run it:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/b2xatestdb
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.gmail.greghess.main.Database.connect(Database.java:47)
at com.gmail.greghess.main.B2XAssistant.main(B2XAssistant.java:19)
```

I have checked over almost everything making sure I have the correct URL, login credentials, the server is up the credentials are valid. I have considered the possibly that it may be because I don't have the following line of code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

However I read somewhere that this line is no longer needed except in older versions of the library. I'm almost certain that the problem is that sublime text 3 is not using the the external jar file so I found the following direction on documentation that they provide [here](https://javatar.readthedocs.org/getting_started.html).

> Dependencies
>
> Javatar supports build and run project that have
>   dependencies .jar files both global and specific projects. To add a
>   dependency to global projects (all projects), go to Javatar
>   Settings... > Dependencies... and select Add External .jar or Add
>   Class Folder and Javatar will show a dialog to select a dependency you
>   want to add. To add a dependency to current project, same as for
>   global projects, but using Project Settings... > Dependencies... menu
>   instead.

Upon executing these instructions I found out that sublime text 3 is not opening up a dialog for me to select a project dependency.

If anyone can help me figure out either the error in my code which is posted on github [here](https://github.com/GregHess/B2XAssistant) or how to get st3 to allow me to set the dependent external jar it would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I am using the following external jar for JDBC: mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar

EDIT #2: I have cloned my repository on another computer and set up sublime text 3 the exact same way and have also run the program without problem. I have found that the problem is that for some reason on my other computer sublime text 3 is not popping up the GUI window for me to add the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could get to work at all was following the instructions [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html) and using a fresh install of Sublime Text 3, Package Control, and Javatar. If anyone has this problem and comes up with a better solution please post but it actually doesn't take all that much time for a fresh install. (Less than 3 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mysql connector is missing from the classpath when Sublime Text 3 tries to run your code. Otherwise, in a console, try to run:

```
java -cp "mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" com.gmail.greghess.main.B2XAssistant
```

Make sure to update the path to the mysql connector jar.

Comment: I understand what your saying and that is what I thought also but how can I update the classpath in sublime text 3 if the dialog doesn't pop up when I try to add the dependency to the the project because I don't want to manually run the program through the console everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I first downloaded **mysql-connector-java** form [here](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.zip). Extract the file. Then in Sublime I went to **Javatar Settings > Dependencies > Add External .jar > path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar** and BINGOOO!!!!